# Create AssetCategory in Lifeary scheduled job

Tags: java, liferay, scheduled-tasks

I have a Liferay scheduled job which should create new `AssetCategories` according to some rules. But I always get an `AssetCategoryNameException`. I have only letters, spaces and parenthesis in my new category's name/title, all of which I used in the existing category names. I also tried with constant string with english letters, with the same result. What could be the cause of this exception?

My code looks like this:

```
AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addCategory(userId, 0, titleMap, null,
     myVocabulary.getVocabularyId(), null, serviceContext);
```

- `userId` is the id of a random Administrator user since it's a scheduled job and there is no "logged in" user.
- `titleMap` is created with the following code: `HashMap<Locale, String> titleMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>(); titleMap.put(myLocale, name);`
- `serviceContext` is a new `ServiceContext` object

And one more thing, how can I use the `categoryProperties` attribute of this method (after the problem is solved)? It is a `String[]`, but properties are key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. The problem was caused by the locale settings. `AssetCategory` has both a name and a localized title, and the `addAssetCategory` method uses the title from the default locale as name. But in my case, the default locale was `en_US` while I was putting only `hu_HU` title in my `titleMap`. So, the title of the default locale was null, and that caused the exception (note: a `NullPointerException` would be more informative...).  So I changed the default locale to my locale, and the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Following are invalid characters for AssetCategoryName

```
public static char[] INVALID_CHARACTERS = new char[] {
        CharPool.AMPERSAND, CharPool.APOSTROPHE, CharPool.AT,
        CharPool.BACK_SLASH, CharPool.CLOSE_BRACKET, CharPool.CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE,
        CharPool.COLON, CharPool.COMMA, CharPool.EQUAL, CharPool.GREATER_THAN,
        CharPool.FORWARD_SLASH, CharPool.LESS_THAN, CharPool.NEW_LINE,
        CharPool.OPEN_BRACKET, CharPool.OPEN_CURLY_BRACE, CharPool.PERCENT,
        CharPool.PIPE, CharPool.PLUS, CharPool.POUND, CharPool.QUESTION,
        CharPool.QUOTE, CharPool.RETURN, CharPool.SEMICOLON, CharPool.SLASH,
        CharPool.STAR, CharPool.TILDE
    };
```

Make sure your category name wont have any of these characters.

Comment: I have the same error even if I use only letters. When I print my `titleMap` var, I got the following result in my last test: `{hu_HU=TO}`. It's very simple, but even this does not work.

Comment: Can you have debug point at isValidWord of AssetUtil.java and check what characters you are getting in word.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not an option now. But i tried to convert my String to byte[] and print the bytes. I got 84 79 which are the required decimal codes. I can set with this method the _titles_, but the exception is about _name_. Is it possible that the name is not set automatically and is null? Is there a way to explicitly set category name?